# Google maps tour won't work inside an iframe

Tags: html, google-maps, iframe, embed

I need to embed this tour to a site:

https://www.google.es/maps/@39.566752,2.649834,3a,75y,113.38h,90t/data=!3m5!1e1!3m3!1s86s2yikaJz6n9Ezi7bJmTw!2e0!3e2

But the thing is that

`<iframe src="https://www.google.es/maps/@39.566752,2.649834,3a,75y,113.38h,90t/data=!3m5!1e1!3m3!1s86s2yikaJz6n9Ezi7bJmTw!2e0!3e2"></iframe>`

Wont display anything

Any suggestion?

Comment: As it seems currently embedding streetviews is not supported by the new maps, use the old maps.

Comment: Hi there, could you explain wat you mean by `old maps` ? thanks!

Comment: `<iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.es/maps?cbll=39.566752,2.649834&amp;layer=c&amp;panoid=86s2yikaJz6n9Ezi7bJmTw&amp;cbp=12,113.38,,0,0&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;ll=39.534762,2.690964&amp;spn=0.237775,1.056747&amp;t=m&amp;z=11&amp;source=embed&amp;output=svembed"></iframe>`

Comment: At the new maps you'll find at the bottom a question-mark. Click on it and choose "return to classic maps". In the classic(old) maps use the embed-code provided when you click on the share-button.

Comment: Hi there, I see now what you mean, but I don't know how to load my tour again into the classic view, the iframe you posted is not showing it... thanks!

Comment: SO has placed some whitespaces in the code, working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/7qqpw/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the new version of Google maps, in order to show your map you need to past the integration version of the link, you can't just past the share URL inside of an iframe because with classic google maps it is trivial to convert from a share link to the iframe embed URL because it essentially has the same URL parameters, you just add an `output=embed` URL parameter so that Google will output the embed layout rather than the desktop site layout.

So that, I think you should use Safari browser, since Google maps is not updated in it for some reason.
For you're case : You need to prcess the url : https://maps.google.es/maps?ll=39.566752,2.649834&spn=0.369997,0.837021&cbll=39.566752,2.649834&layer=c&panoid=86s2yikaJz6n9Ezi7bJmTw&cbp=12,113.38,,0,0&t=m&z=11

And here'd how I do it :

```
$url = $options["url"];
$url = parse_url($url);
$query = array();
parse_str( $url['query'], $query );
$iframe = "<iframe  marginheight=\"0\" marginwidth=\"0\" "; 
$iframe .= "src=\"https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q";    
$iframe .= "&amp;source=s_q";   
$iframe .= "&amp;hl=fr";    
$iframe .= "&amp;geocode="; 
if(isset($query['q'])) $iframe .= "&amp;q=".$query['q'];    
$iframe .= "&amp;aq=";  
if(isset($query['sll'])) $iframe .= "&amp;sll=".$query['sll'];  
if(isset($query['sspn'])) $iframe .= "&amp;sspn=".$query['sspn'];
$iframe .= "&amp;t=m";
$iframe .= "&amp;ie=UTF8";
if(isset($query['hq'])) $iframe .= "&amp;hq=".$query['hq'];
if(isset($query['hnear'])) $iframe .= "&amp;hnear=".$query['hnear'];
if(isset($query['ll'])) $iframe .= "&amp;ll=".$query['ll'];
if(isset($query['spn'])) $iframe .= "&amp;spn=".$query['spn'];
if(isset($query['z'])) $iframe .= "&amp;z=".$query['z'];
if(isset($query['iwloc'])) $iframe .= "&amp;iwloc=".$query['iwloc']; else $iframe .= "&amp;iwloc=";
$iframe .= "&amp;output=embed\">";
$iframe .= "</iframe>";
```

this will generate something like this :

```
<iframe  src="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=fr&amp;geocode=&amp;aq=&amp;t=m&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;ll=39.566752,2.649834&amp;spn=0.369997,0.837021&amp;z=11&amp;iwloc=&amp;output=embed" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" s12546768360786571550="true" replaced="true"></iframe>
```

The iframee generated it only give you the area selected by google maps, it you want the google tour add this iframe :

```
<iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.es/maps?cbll=39.566752,2.649834&amp;layer=c&amp;panoid=86s2yikaJz6n9Ezi7bJmTw&amp;cbp=12,113.38,,0,0&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;ll=39.566752,2.649834&amp;spn=0.369997,0.837021&amp;t=m&amp;z=11&amp;source=embed&amp;output=svembed"></iframe><br /><small><a href="https://maps.google.es/maps?cbll=39.566752,2.649834&amp;layer=c&amp;panoid=86s2yikaJz6n9Ezi7bJmTw&amp;cbp=12,113.38,,0,0&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;ll=39.566752,2.649834&amp;spn=0.369997,0.837021&amp;t=m&amp;z=11&amp;source=embed" style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left">Agrandir le plan</a></small>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7Ydbk/2/)

Comment: Thank you very much for you anser but: `https://www.google.es/maps/@39.566752,2.649834,3a,75y,113.38h,90t/data=!3m5!1e1!3m3!1s86s2yikaJz6n9Ezi7bJmTw!2e0!3e2&output=embed` fails, was that what you mean?

Comment: Hi, i don't really understand what you're trying to do. But you code generates this iframe: `<iframe  marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=fr&amp;geocode=&amp;aq=&amp;t=m&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;iwloc=&amp;output=embed"></iframe>`  and  it's not the tour:  http://jsfiddle.net/7Ydbk/ Any thoughts? thanks!